# What is the equation for fuel equals distance for a rocket?

Tags: rockets, spacecraft, fuel, mathematics

Theoretically, I am trying to launch a rocket from space and trying to figure out how much fuel I would need to get to a certain distance.

Comment: Your question unfortunately doesn't make that much sense, getting somewhere in space is partly a function of time. How far do you want to go, and how long do you want to take to get there, then you have to account for gravity.

Comment: Perhaps the Heinlein equation: "If you can get your ship into orbit, you're halfway to anywhere."

Comment: Distance takes time, not fuel.

Comment: [delta-v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v) is the parameter that most closely relates the amount of fuel a rocket burns to what that rocket can do. Where the rocket can go with that delta-V depends heavily on where it is, and what it's doing as it spends it.

Answer (score 8):

**There is no limit how much distance a rocket can travel once it has exceeded escape velocity.** So there is no simple relationship between fuel and distance.

[Voyager 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1) ran out of fuel many years ago, but is currently traveling at a speed of 17 km/s (11 mi/s) relative to the Sun. It will continue traveling at this speed for the foreseeable future and will be at a distance of a lightyear in about 18,000 years.

[Newton's first law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton%27s_first_law) says that in the absence of forces, a body in motion will continue with that same motion indefinitely. When there is gravity, once a rocket exceeds its local escape velocity it will continue traveling forever.